# How to skip unwanted elements using XML::Twig?

Tags: perl, xml-twig

Trying to learn [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) and fetch some data from an XML document.

My XML contains 20k+ `<ADN>` elements. Eaach `<ADN>` element contains tens of child elements, one of them is the `<GID>`. I want process only those `ADN` where the `GID` == 1. (See the example XML is the `__DATA__`)

The docs says:

> Handlers are triggered in fixed order, sorted by their type (xpath
>   expressions first, then regexps, then level), then by whether they
>   specify a full path (starting at the root element) or not, then by
>   number of steps in the expression , then number of predicates, then
>   number of tests in predicates. Handlers where the last step does not
>   specify a step (foo/bar/*) are triggered after other XPath handlers.
>   Finally *all* handlers are triggered last.
>
> Important: once a handler has been triggered if it returns 0 then no
>   other handler is called, except a *all* handler which will be called
>   anyway.

My actual code:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;

my $cat = load_xml_catalog();
say Dumper $cat;

sub load_xml_catalog {
        my $hr;
        my $current;
        my $twig= XML::Twig->new(
        twig_roots => {
            ADN => sub {      # process the <ADN> elements
                $_->purge;    # and purge when finishes with one
            },
        },
        twig_handlers => {
            'ADN/GID' => sub {
                return 1 if $_->trimmed_text == 1;
                return 0;     # skip the other handlers - if the GID != 1
            },

            'ADN/ID' => sub { #remember the ID as a "key" into the '$hr' for the "current" ADN
                $current = $_->trimmed_text;
                $hr->{$current}{$_->tag} = $_->trimmed_text;
            },

            #rules for the wanted data extracting & storing to $hr->{$current}
            'ADN/Name' => sub {
                $hr->{$current}{$_->tag} = $_->text;
            },
        },
        );
        $twig->parse(\*DATA);
    return $hr;
}
__DATA__
<ArrayOfADN>
    <ADN>
        <GID>1</GID>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>name 1</Name>
    </ADN>
    <ADN>
        <GID>2</GID>
        <ID>20</ID>
        <Name>should be skipped because GID != 1</Name>
    </ADN>
    <ADN>
        <GID>1</GID>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>other name 1000</Name>
    </ADN>
</ArrayOfADN>
```

It outputs

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1000' => {
                    'ID' => '1000',
                    'Name' => 'other name 1000'
                  },
          '1' => {
                 'Name' => 'name 1',
                 'ID' => '1'
               },
          '20' => {
                  'Name' => 'should be skipped because GID != 1',
                  'ID' => '20'
                }
        };
```

So,

- The handler for the `ADN/GID` returns `0` when the GID != 1.
- Why the other handlers are still called?
- The expected (wanted) output is without the `'20' => ...` .
- How to skip the unwanted nodes correctly?

Comment: @toolic According the doc, _Handlers are triggered in fixed order_ , so probably me doesn't understand how the order is determined - aka, how to solve the above... ;)

Comment: The problem is - the handers trigger in a fixed order _for a particular element_. They reset for each separate one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "returns zero" thing is a bit of a red herring in this context. If you had multiple matches on your element, then *one* of them returning zero would inhibit the others.

That doesn't mean it won't still try and process subsequent nodes.

I think you're getting confused - you have handlers for separate subelements of your `<ADN>` elements - and they trigger separately. That's by design. There is a precedence order for `xpath` but only on duplicate matches. Yours are completely separate though, so they all 'fire' because they trigger on different elements.

However, you might find it useful to know - `twig_handlers` allows `xpath` expressions - so you can explicitly say:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
my $twig = XML::Twig->parse( \*DATA );
$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');

foreach my $ADN ( $twig -> findnodes('//ADN/GID[string()="1"]/..') ) {
   $ADN -> print;
}
```

This also works in the `twig_handlers` syntax. I would suggest doing a handler is only really useful if you need to pre-process your XML, or you're memory constrained. With 20,000 nodes, you may be. (at which point `purge` is your friend).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
   pretty_print  => 'indented_a',
   twig_handlers => {
      '//ADN[string(GID)="1"]' => sub { $_->print }
   }
);

$twig->parse( \*DATA );


__DATA__
<ArrayOfADN>
    <ADN>
        <GID>1</GID>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>name 1</Name>
    </ADN>
    <ADN>
        <GID>2</GID>
        <ID>20</ID>
        <Name>should be skipped because GID != 1</Name>
    </ADN>
    <ADN>
        <GID>1</GID>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>other name 1000</Name>
    </ADN>
</ArrayOfADN>
```

Although, I would probably just do it this way instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub process_ADN {
    my ( $twig, $ADN ) = @_; 
    return unless $ADN -> first_child_text('GID') == 1;
    print "ADN with name:", $ADN -> first_child_text('Name')," Found\n";
}


my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
   pretty_print  => 'indented_a',
   twig_handlers => {
      'ADN' => \&process_ADN
   }
);

$twig->parse( \*DATA );


__DATA__
<ArrayOfADN>
    <ADN>
        <GID>1</GID>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>name 1</Name>
    </ADN>
    <ADN>
        <GID>2</GID>
        <ID>20</ID>
        <Name>should be skipped because GID != 1</Name>
    </ADN>
    <ADN>
        <GID>1</GID>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>other name 1000</Name>
    </ADN>
</ArrayOfADN>
```

Comment: Is there any way to skip an element if it has a sub string? e.g. I want to ignore all `<fo:block>` which has "Reference Manual" in `<fo:block font-family="Helvetica,Symbol,ZapfDingbats,Arial Unicode" font-size="10pt" font-weight="bold" line-height="12pt" padding-bottom="0.5mm" text-align="center">Reference Manual, Rev. 3, 10/2018</fo:block>`